# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to the android i am trying to get the cursor values related to the particular column value. but it's showing null.

```
 public int getDashBoardCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DASHBOARD_TABLE + " WHERE " + VECHICAL_TYPE + " = " + 'c';
```

From here also i am getting no such column: c (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM dashboard_table WHERE vehicle_type = c

```
     String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DASHBOARD_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}

public DashBoardAvaCapModel getVechicalRelAva(String vechical_type) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    DashBoardAvaCapModel dash = null;

    try {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(DASHBOARD_TABLE, new String[]{_ID,
                        AVAILABLE, CAPACITY, BOOKED, VECHICAL_TYPE}, VECHICAL_TYPE + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(vechical_type)}, null, null, null, null);

        int idkey = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(_ID);
        int available = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AVAILABLE);
        int capactity = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(CAPACITY);
        int booked = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(BOOKED);
        int vechicaltype = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(VECHICAL_TYPE);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())

            dash = new DashBoardAvaCapModel(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(idkey)),
                    cursor.getString(available), cursor.getString(capactity), cursor.getString(booked), cursor.getString(vechicaltype));
        Log.e("dash", "" + cursor.getString(available));

    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        String exp = String.valueOf(ex);
        Log.e("Databa", "" + exp);
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }

    return dash;

}
```

Comment: What is `VECHICAL_TYPE` defined as? Can you post your `CREATE TABLE` statement? At the moment you're using `VECHICAL_TYPE` as both the column name and the argument, so effectively you're saying `WHERE VECHICAL_TYPE = VECHICAL_TYPE`.

Comment: @marcin  vechical_type is string,

Comment: create table statement is      String DASHBOARD_SAVING = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DASHBOARD_TABLE + "("
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + AVAILABLE + " TEXT ,"
                + CAPACITY + " TEXT ,"
                + BOOKED + " TEXT ,"
                + VECHICAL_TYPE + " TEXT "
                + ")";

Comment: And what is `VEHICAL_TYPE`? i.e. `VEHICAL_TYPE = ...`

Comment: @Michael vechical_type is String value reference it is a column id reference;

Comment: @ Michael  My data table should be like 

id available capacity booked vechical_type
1     3            97           3             c"referrer's car"
2     4            150         4             b""referrer's bike"

Comment: Out of interest, what happens when you rename the function's argument `vechical_type` (lowercase) to something else? That would also clear up some confusion in the code.

Comment: Namely because having 3 very similar variable names (`VECHICAL_TYPE`, `vechical_type` and `vechicaltype`) could confuse someone else reading your code.

Comment: @Michael I change the identifier's names & send u to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing this line

```
   cursor = db.query(DASHBOARD_TABLE, new String[]{_ID,
                    AVAILABLE, CAPACITY, BOOKED, VECHICAL_TYPE}, VECHICAL_TYPE + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(vechical_type)}, null, null, null, null);
```

pls try to write

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

For first one you can use like

```
String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DASHBOARD_TABLE + " WHERE " + VECHICAL_TYPE + " = '" + c + "'"
```

> where c is any variable

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Aman thankd for quick responce,I  all ready used this,but it is not working

Comment: which line you are getting the error? can you pls specify

Comment: after cursor.movetofirst I am trying to retrive the value but I is showing error cursor is out of boundary exception

Comment: @AMANSINGH `cursor.moveToFirst()` is already used in the code Aravind posted

Comment: in first line try with
`String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DASHBOARD_TABLE + " WHERE " + VECHICAL_TYPE + " = 'c'"  ;`

Comment: @AMANSINGN  your logic is working but i need the vechical_type 'c' related Data; then how can i do that one

Comment: Hi , @AMAN SINGN As U said i pass the vechical_type as a char value then also i get the same exception the 2nd method is not working .

Comment: Hi , @AMAN SINGN Please Guide me what is the problem on that code. i didn't get the values

Comment: why not you try once wid simple way like ` Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cartitems WHERE id.....`